# write path with '$' character in Latex

Tags: path, latex

I have a Latex relation to write and I need to insert a path related to a server resouce.
I need insert the following path: `\\srvfc\e$\TestFolder`

My problem is to insert the `$` character inside the path.
I've tried both `\path{\\srvfc\e\$\TestFolder}` and `\path{\\srvfc\e$\TestFolder}` strings,  but no result is good!

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me if you mean something like the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

Try this: \url{\\srvfc\e$\TestFolder}

\end{document}
```

Otherwise, if you'd like to have the path to your resource clickable, you may prefer to use package [`hyperref`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) instead of `url`.

**Addendum:** a bit heavier,

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\textbackslash \textbackslash srvfc\textbackslash e\$\textbackslash TestFolder}

\end{document}
```

is another option. No package is needed to run it but notice how the dollar sign must be escaped here (`\$`).

Comment: I'm not asking for a clickable resource... I need to print on my final paper a path that contains the `$` character. Your solution is not good because in your case the `$` character is translated as a latex token. Indeed, in Latex you can use the `$` token to wrap a word and obtain an ''italic effect''.

Comment: As you use it like a wrapper, then (in theory) untill you insert again that character the compiler won't be able to close the ''italic'' sequence. The latex compile error is: `! Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: Right, interesting thing the one about the tokens. "Italic" sequence is inline math notation instead. Can you please reference the use of \path command outside TikZ-pgf? I never used it this way before. So we see what we can do with it. Thank you.

Comment: @baru I edited my answer, you should now be able to compile both examples. Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/when-should-one-use-verb-and-when-texttt.