# LaTeX: How to define a path with special characters?

Tags: latex, escaping

I'm trying to include a .csv file into my LaTeX document in order to plot its data. However, I struggle with setting its path correctly.

This is what I was trying first:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.95\linewidth
        ]
        
        \addplot+[
        mark=*]
        table[col sep=comma, x=x, y=y1]{data/Cuba [filter: 10 $\leq$ size $\leq$ 20]_normalized_nodes_a5aa37ded2f2837de689914432ad84f3.csv};
        \addlegendentry{some legend};   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

does not work *for obvious reasons*.

Then I tried to escape it:

```
...
table[col sep=comma, x=x, y=y1]{\verb|data/Cuba [filter: 10 $\leq$ size $\leq$ 20]_normalized_nodes_a5aa37ded2f2837de689914432ad84f3.csv|};
...
```

which also failed:

> Missing $ inserted. ...odes_a5aa37ded2f2837de689914432ad84f3.csv| };

I also tried to escape each special character by hand (which is not the solution I am looking for): `_` becomes `\_`, `$` becomes `\$` and so on. But it still did not work since the `\` where still included in the search path.

Lastly, it tired the `\url{}` package ([write path with '$' character in Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000144/write-path-with-character-in-latex)) which did also not work:

```
line 32: \textfont 0 is undefined (character d). ...2837de689914432ad84f3.csv} };
line 32: \textfont 0 is undefined (character a). ...2837de689914432ad84f3.csv} };
line 32: \textfont 0 is undefined (character t). ...2837de689914432ad84f3.csv} };
line 32: \textfont 0 is undefined (character a). ...2837de689914432ad84f3.csv} };
line 32: \textfont 0 is undefined (character /).
```

How can I easily fix this issue? Isn't there any `verb` like command which does not require math mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use special characters in file names